# Location of output files in visual studio testing

Tags: visual-studio, testing

When one runs test in visual studio, we can see the output in a tab named :

```
Test Output - MyTestName - version numer - run number
```

Does anyone know how to get the **location** of the file being display in the tab files ?
I am not able to 'save as' which would give me a hint.

Specifically, I'd like to see the results of previous runs.

Answer (score 0):

For Coded UI and for Web and Load tests, the test results are stored in the **TestResults** directory which is normally in the same directory as the solution (ie the **.sln**) file. The directory normally hold the results of the most recent 25 runs.

The **TestContext** object within a Coded UI test has a number of members with **Directory** in their name allowing access to the various directories while the test is running.

Comment: Your question does not state what sort of tests you are running, so I assumed you were using the standard test types available in Visual Studio. Coded UI (also Web and Load tests) are two of the test types supported out of the box by Visual Studio. What is xunit? Web searching suggests it is not a Microsoft supported test mechanism.

Comment: it is a very widespread testing engine. I run it through the standard vsexecutionengine suit of visual, so I thought all this would be standardized. no testresults directory in my case, obviously. thank you for your answer though.

Comment: I have this same question but TestResults does not seem to hold any of the text shown in the test results.  Folders show up after some of the tests are run, but other tests, add nothing even though I can see results from the last test. The folders that do show up are empty.  I scanned the entire solution folder and can't find the text for the test run anywhere.  This make me wonder whether or not VS is putting somewhere I do not want on my machine .  Perhaps a storage leak as well?  Very annoying.

Comment: @BigTFromAZ Why not write the various "directory" values from `TestContext` to some output file. For example `C:\Temp\BigTFromAZ.log` (assuming `C:\Temp\` exists).

Comment: @AdrianHHH I think that's sound advice. Maybe I should add Nlog to the test projects, and use it to record results. This way developers can stream their logs locally. Our build server can be configured to stream it's test output somewhere more permanent, perhaps to Azure Storage.